# Call cannot come into asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am Novice in asterisk I installed Asterisk but now when I calling with telephony call cannot
come into asterisk &
I config ed Outgoing call bat call cannot out asterisk when I write(asterisk -vvvvvr)
& I calling with outdoor display for me

> -- Executing [09396464991@DLPN_Main:1] Macro("SIP/6001-00000000", "trunkdial -failover-0.3,DAHDI/g2/09396464991,DAHDI/g1/09396464991,trunk_1,trunk_1") in newstack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:1] GotoIf("SIP/6001-00000000","0?1-fmsetcid,1") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:2] GotoIf("SIP/6001-00000000","0?1-setgbobname,1") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:3] Set("SIP/6001-00000000", "CALLERID(num)=6001") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:4] Set("SIP/6001-00000000", "CALLERID(all)=") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:5] GotoIf("SIP/6001-00000000","0?1-dial,1") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:6] Set("SIP/6001-00000000", "CALLERID(all)=") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:7] Set("SIP/6001-00000000", "CALLERID(all)=") in new stack
>
> -- Executing [s@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:8] Goto("SIP/6001-00000000", "1-dial,1") in new stack
>
> -- Goto (macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3,1-dial,1)
>
> -- Executing [1-dial@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:1] Dial("SIP/6001-00000000:", "DAHDI/g2/09396464991") in new stack
>
> **[Mar 10 13:40:04] ****WARNING[2106]: channel.c:5627 ast_request: No channel type registered for 'DAHDI'**
>
> **[Mar 10 13:40:04] WARNING[2106]: app_dial.c:2274 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'DAHDI' (cause 66 - Channel not implemented)**== Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
>
> -- Executing [1-dial@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:2] GotoIf("SIP/6001-00000000", "20 > 0?1-CHANUNAVAIL,1:1-out,1") in new stack
>
> -- Goto (macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3,1-CHANUNAVAIL,1)
>
> -- Executing [1-CHANUNAVAIL@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:1] Dial("SIP/6001-00000000", "DAHDI/g1/09396464991") in new stack [Mar 10 13:40:04] WARNING[2106]: channel.c:5627 ast_request: No channel type registered for 'DAHDI'
>
> **[Mar 10 13:40:04] WARNING[2106]: app_dial.c:2274 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'DAHDI' (cause 66 - Channel not implemented)== Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
>
> -- Executing [1-CHANUNAVAIL@macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3:2] Hangup("SIP/6001-00000000", "") in new stack**== Spawn extension (macro-trunkdial-failover-0.3, 1-CHANUNAVAIL, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/6001-00000000' in macro 'trunkdial-failover-0.3'== Spawn extension (DLPN_Main, 09396464991, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/6001-00

Comment: Firstly, please ensure you have dahdi.  Secondly, here is a bug that could be related to your issue: https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/AGUI-225

Comment: I Could resolving  tanks ! I config ed

Answer (score 0):

1) First check your dahdi config is present and it is ok. Use following to check it

```
 dahdi_cfg -vvvv
```

2) check that your asterisk have pri/dahdi support.